# Simple Logic Error in Python

Tags: python, function, csv

Why doesn't the 3rd row of the CSV output have `"hola"`?

The (`if levels[a] == "3"`) should ensure it's set to `"hola"`.

Thanks for any ideas or help!

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
levels = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"]]
def column1Logic(self):
    self.column1 = "logic worked"
    self.column1 = self.greeting
class Row(object):
    column1 = "name"
    greeting = "oh"
    def __init__(self, level, greeting):
        self.level = level
        self.greeting = greeting
    def rowEntry(self, level, greeting):
        column1Logic(self)
        lol = [[self.column1]]
        lol[0] = self.column1
        file_writer.writerow([o for o in lol])
with open("test.csv", "wb") as test_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for a in range(0, len(levels)):
        if levels[a] == "3":
            greeting = "hola"
            food = Row(levels[a], greeting)
            food.rowEntry(levels[a], greeting)
        else:
            greeting = "hi"
            food = Row(levels[a], greeting)
            food.rowEntry(levels[a], greeting)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over a list of lists. Therefore you should check if you get `['3']` instead of just `'3'`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
levels = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"]]
def column1Logic(self):
    self.column1 = "logic worked"
    self.column1 = self.greeting

class Row(object):
    column1 = "name"
    greeting = "oh"
    def __init__(self, level, greeting):
        self.level = level
        self.greeting = greeting
    def rowEntry(self, level, greeting):
        column1Logic(self)
        lol = [[self.column1]]
        lol[0] = self.column1
        file_writer.writerow([o for o in lol])

with open("test.csv", "wb") as test_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for a in range(0, len(levels)):
        print levels[a]
        if levels[a] == ['3']:  # instead of levels[a] == "3"
            greeting = "hola"
            food = Row(levels[a], greeting)
            food.rowEntry(levels[a], greeting)
        else:
            greeting = "hi"
            food = Row(levels[a], greeting)
            food.rowEntry(levels[a], greeting)
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! to @ Khalil Ammour he commented it there in the fix (# instead of levels[a] == "3")

Comment: @Bob Willaker yep, that is how you accept the answer